# Custom build for TinyMCE 5

Tags: tinymce

I see that we can build a custom build of TinyMCE 4 using https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/custom-builds/
Is there a similar custom builder for newer versions of TinyMCE (5 or 6)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build customizer for TinyMCE 5 or 6. You can only download the whole package at once: https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/

However, if you are not using some of the plugins or skins, you can remove them manually. Plugins are located in `/tinymce/plugins/`, skins are in `/tinymce/skins/`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Any idea which is the recommended version to be used - TinyMCE4 or 5 or 6?

Comment: It's always your choice to make. Depends on your requirements. TinyMCE 4 is no longer supported, so won't recommend that. You can see what's changed in TinyMCE 6 compared to 5 here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/